# Insert a character ' ' on a column of a record [SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server

What i wanted to do is update the rows of a column named subject_code
into this format

- 'LC410' -> 'LC 410'
- 'MS200' -> 'MS 200'

How can I insert a ' ' between the letter and number character?

[dbo.Subject] columns

```
id
subject_code
subject_desc
```

Comment: Are all current subject codes 5 characters in format xxnnn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It searches for the index of numeric character and stuffs space

```
update subject SET subject_code =  STUFF(subject_code,
                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',subject_code),0,' ') ;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1675c/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use concat and patindex function to search for numeric and letters.

```
update subject
subject_code = concat(left(subject_code, patindex('%[0-9]%', subject_code)-1),
' ', right(subject_code, patindex('%[a-z,A-Z]%', 
reverse(subject_code))-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as a guide:

```
declare @table table (subject_code varchar(100))
insert into @table values
('LS100'),('MSS120'),('M121')

update @table set subject_code = stuff(subject_code, patindex('%[A-Za-z][0-9]%', subject_code) + 1, 0, ' ')

select * from @table
```

The code finds first occurence of digit following a letter (using `patindex` function) and insertes space between them (with `stuff` function).